# dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable - Ubuntu 12 - Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, vagrant

I am working on setting up a Vagrant / Puppet install so that new developers can have a clean development environment for our Rails project.

The basic Vagrant configure commands are:

```
  config.vm.box      = 'precise32'
  config.vm.box_url  = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box'
```

Overall, the install seems to be going well.  I've got RVM, Postgres, and Ruby installed and running.

However, whenever I try to install the "Heroku Toolbelt" using this command:

```
su -l vagrant -c 'wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh'
```

I run into this problem:

```
... Lots of Hits and downloads...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
Suggested packages:
  ruby1.9.1-examples ri1.9.1 graphviz ruby1.9.1-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 132 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,997 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

(*Note*) This happens if I run the command manually after vagrant ssh.  Also, the actual shell configuration gets the error when it initially runs.

Since this is a vagrant box, it is easy to 'vagrant destroy' and then try again but I get the same issue consistently.

The strange thing is, my PATH does definitely include those folders:

```
echo $PATH
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin
```

the file 'ldconfig' is in /sbin and is an executable:

```
cd /sbin
ls -l l*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    465 Apr 20  2012 ldconfig
```

Same with start-stop-daemon:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26752 Apr 12  2012 start-stop-daemon
```

So, not sure what it is really complaining about... Any suggestions?  Some permissions issue with Vagrant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are piping your wget to a new shell, the environment is not preserved.

To prove this, try the following from inside your vagrant box

```
root@lucid32:~# export PATH=$PATH:/foo
root@lucid32:~# echo $PATH  
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin:/foo
```

Now run the same command as a different user

```
root@lucid32:~# su -l vagrant -c 'echo $PATH' 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin
```

Compare the output of both commands and you will see that the environment is not preserved on the child shell. (/foo disappeared)

To make the environment persistent, use `--preserve-environment`  or `-p` or `-m`. All 3 are equivalent.

```
root@lucid32:~# export PATH=$PATH:/foo
root@lucid32:~# su --preserve-environment -l vagrant -c 'echo $PATH' 
-su: /root/.bash_profile: Permission denied
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin:/foo:/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin
```

*Don't worry about the permission denied error, that is expected*

## Solutions

---

**Solution 1.**

Use `-p`, `-m` or `--preserve-environment`

```
su --preserve-environment -l vagrant -c   'wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh'
```

Tested on lucid32 vagrant box (10.04)

**Solution 2.**

If your puppet manifest runs before your heroku script, simply add /sbin to the vagrant user's path through puppet

---

Tested lucid32 with the following commands

```
root@lucid32:~# su --preserve-environment -l vagrant -c 'wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh'
-su: /root/.bash_profile: Permission denied
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
--2013-08-20 07:40:13--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key
....
root@lucid32:~# su vagrant -
vagrant@lucid32:/root$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email:
```

Comment: Thanks @spuder for your well-clarified answer!  I'm having some trouble though.  When I try your example of su --preserve-environment -l vagrant -c 'echo $PATH' the /foo still doesn't show (just as it doesn't in your first example)    I destroyed and recreated the box and same thing.  I'll keep playing around... Your comments have at least given me some leads!

Comment: @DaveCollins I just double checked my steps, and it works for me. /foo will only exist on the shell until it is closed. make sure you don't logout, or reboot the machine in the middle of the test.

Comment: Well, for whatever reason the --preserve-environment just does not work on my vagrant box.  However, I just tried the internal command without sudo and it ran just fine!  Very odd.  Your answer gave me much insight as to what was going wrong, though!